# Dynamic constructor calling in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, subtyping

Assume I have 4 classes: `A`, `B`, `SA` and `SB` where `B extends A`
and `SB extends SA`.

Class `A` has the following constructor:

```
private SA a;
public A() {
   a = new SA();
}
```

Obviously when I'm calling the contructor for class `B` and since `B extends A`
constructor of class `A` is also called. But in such a case I would like the
constructor of `A` to do `a = new SB();` instead of `a = new SA();`.

Is there an easy way to do this without
changing the public interfaces of both `A` and `B`?

Comment: Dependency Injection! _without changing the public interfaces of both A and B_? Not really.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok how would you if you could change the public interfaces of `A` or `B`? What would be the easiest way (less changes) to go?

Comment: Make `A`'s constructor accept an `SA` argument.

Comment: Why is the constructor of `A` necessarily called? That only happens if you call `super` in `B`'s constructor.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Errr... No. [JLS §8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7): _If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();"_

Comment: @BoristheSpider How do you know class `B` does not have a constructor? We have no information about how B works.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I don't get you. Every constructor call **must** either begin with a call to _another_ constructor or the compiler will add a call to `super()`. So `super()` will **always** be called. How else would the superclass be constructed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Hmm I was thinking of when arguments are involved. My apologies.

Comment: @thatidiotguy if the superclass does not have a no-args constructor then it is a compile time error if that superclass constructor is not explicitly called.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understand sir, you can go about your other business.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have a `public` constructor and a `protected` constructor:

```
private SA a;
public A() {
   this(new SA());
}
protected A(final SA a) {
   this.a = a;
}
```

Then in `B`:

```
public B() {
   super(new SB());
}
```

Comment: What if the 2 classes are in different packages. You couldn't do `super(new SB());`. since `A(final SA a)` is protected

Comment: @foobar nope, the whole point of `protected` is that is can be accessed by subclasses in another package. Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. For example :

```
public A(YourEnum en) {
    if (en == YourEnum.SA){
        a = new SA();
    } else {
        a = new SB();
    }
}
```

Also, depends on what you really need, it can be done by overloading constructors

```
public A(){
    a = new SA();
}

public A(YourObjectYouNeed dataNeededForAnotherConstructor){
    //doing initialization stuff
    a = new SB();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look particularly maintainable. What if I now add a `C` that extends `A` and I want an `SC` passed in? Suddenly OCP is violated.

Comment: You're adding a whole new dependency instead of removing one.